# what is the meaning of a "Teardown Report"

Tags: documentation, terminology

I am sorry if this a wrong place to ask the question.

I saw the usage "Teardown report" for a product

What does it mean?

Comment: Could it be [for this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_teardown)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **teardown report** is a summary of disassembling a product.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_teardown):

> A product teardown, or simply teardown, is the act of disassembling a
>   product, such as a television set, to identify its component parts and
>   functions. For products having secret technology, such as the
>   Mikoyan-Gurevich MiG-25, the process may be secret. For others,
>   including consumer electronics, the results are typically disseminated
>   through photographs and component lists so that others can make use of
>   the information without having to disassemble the product themselves.